# How to define a column that can automate capitalizing?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

So that when you insert 'abc',it'll be converted to 'ABC' automatically.

I'm using MySQL,is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write an INSERT  trigger that does this for you.

Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Capitalize BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
SET NEW.MyColumn = UPPER(NEW.MyColumn)
```

Comment: From 5.0 onwards as far as I can see.

Comment: Is it a typo,NEW should beg MyTable?

Comment: No, that's a built-in reference to the newly to be inserted row. Only available in triggers.

Answer (score -1):

What about using Upper function while executing query ?
lets say You are using a SP to insert the values ... cast the value to upper case using UPPER function and then insert ?

Comment: I guess regardless of *how* it gets inserted, the OP wants to make sure it is fully capitalized; a trigger would ensure this behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

this really should be done before it is passed to the DB